# Covariant derivative 1+3 formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation

I can't find the proof for the following equation:

> $$ \nabla_bu_a=D_bu_a-A_au_b $$

where $D_b$ is the spatial derivatives respect to $h_{ab}=g_{ab}+u_au_b$ in the 1+3 formalism and $A_a=u^b\nabla_bu_a$.

EDIT:

I want to see it by computation: I start from $h_{ab}=g_{ab}+u_au_b$ and I see that $h^c\vphantom{h}_ah^d\vphantom{h}_b= \delta^c\vphantom{h}_a\delta^d\vphantom{h}_b +u^cu_a\delta^d\vphantom{h}_b+u^du_b\delta^c\vphantom{h}_a + u^du_bu^au_c $. Then I compute

$$D_au_b=h^c\vphantom{h}_ah^d\vphantom{h}_b\nabla_cu_d=\nabla_au_b+u^cu_a\nabla_cu_b+u^cu_au^du_b\nabla_cu_d+u^du_b\nabla_au_d$$

How can I show the last three therms to be exactly $A_au_b$?

Comment: That's just writing the left hand side as a tangential component, which the spatial derivative, and a normal component, which is the expression with A.

Comment: I edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $u^d$ is the unit normal vector to the hypersurface, we have $u^du_d=-1$, implying 
$$0=\nabla_a(u^du_d)=u_d\nabla_au^d+u^d\nabla_a u_d.$$
Then, using $u_d=g_{db}u^b$ and passing $g_{db}$ through $\nabla_a$, we see 
$$2u^d\nabla_a u_d=0.$$
The last two terms are of this form, hence vanish. The first is the one you want to be left over.